# PHP Alphanumeric Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP, and very new to Regular Expressions. I am currently trying to write a Regular Expression that makes sure the characters are all Alpha Numeric, and that accepts other characters a well. I would like to accept áéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ and @.+-*. To accept all alphanumeric characters, and the symbols @.+-*. I use the expression:

```
if (!preg_match("!^[\w@.-]*$!")
```

Also, before I continue I would like to add. These are values being grabbed from a form input, and they should all be one word phrases (as in no spaces). Ok now lets continue! :D Now I want to grab the characters áéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ as well. When I use the expression:

```
if (!preg_match("/[\wáéíñóúüÁÉÍÑÓÚÜ@.\+-].*/")
```

It does not seem to work, could anyone please help? If you are confused, or it is worded bad just ask and I will rewrite it :)

**UPDATE**

My expression:

```
if (!preg_match("!^[\w@.-]*$!")
```

does work, it is the other one that is not working. Thank You! :)

**UPDATE 2**

Now when I try the expression:

```
if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~", $email)) {
```

with the input of michael.jonesáéí@gmail.com it raises a error. There error it raises is "Email contains restricted characters." because I made it say that. Here is the specific code I am using:

```
<?php
if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~", $email)) {
?>
<div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Email contains restricted characters.</div>
<?php } ?>  
                                                }
```

and here is all of the code I am using:

```
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $emailtest1 = False;
                                    $emailtest2 = False;
                                    $emailtest3 = False;
                                    $emailtest4 = False;
                                    $emailtest5 = False;

                                    // Test #1 - Makes sure there is a input

                                    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
?>
                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Please enter your email. </div>
<?php
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        $emailtest1 = True;

                                        // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not already exist

                                        $usernamequery = "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email";

                                        $usernameparams = array(':email' => $_POST['email']);

                                        try{
                                            $emailstmt = $connection->prepare($usernamequery);
                                            $emailresult = $emailstmt->execute($usernameparams);
                                        }

                                        catch(PDOException $ex){
                                            echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
                                        }

                                        $emailcolumns = $emailstmt->fetch();

                                        if($emailcolumns){
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> This email already exists. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $emailtest2 = True;

                                            // Test #3 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                            if(strlen($email) < 5 ) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Email is to short. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            elseif(strlen($email) > 75 ) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Email is to long. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $emailtest3 = True;

                                                // Test #4 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                                if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~", $email)) {
?>
                                                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Email contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php       
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    $emailtest4 = True;

                                                    // Test #5 - Makes sure the email is valid

                                                    if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
?>
                                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> Not a valid email. </div>
<?php       
                                                    }

                                                    else {
                                                        $emailtest5 = True;

                                                        // Final Check

                                                        if (($emailtest1 = True) and ($emailtest2 = True) and ($emailtest3 = True) and ($emailtest4 = True) and ($emailtest5 = True)) {
                                                            // Email is valid! :D
                                                        }

                                                        else {
?>
                                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }   
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Regex to accept all alphanumeric characters, and the symbols @.+-.

```
^[\p{L}\p{N}@+.-]+$
```

Your regex `^[\w@.-]*$` won't match the accented characters. That is `\w` would match only the English alphabets,  digits `0-9` plus the underscore symbol.

- `\p{L}` matches any kind of letter from any language
- `\p{N}` matches any kind of numeric character in any script.
- `+` after the char class would repeat the previous token one or more times. I suggest you to use `+` instead of `*` because `*` repeats the previous token zero or more times. So it matches empty strings also.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/7)

**Update:**

You ust need to include the unicode modifier `u`, so that it would make `\p{L}` to match accented characters.

```
if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~u", $email)) {
```

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you also explained where the OP went wrong.

Comment: @ruakh i think i explained.

Comment: @Tom: I think you've misparsed the sentence you quote. Avinash Raj means "`\w` will only match certain kinds of letters from certain languages".

Comment: @ruakh He didn't wrote that it matches some/certain letter. He wrote that it won't match any letter.

Comment: @ruakh you're correct. I need to improve my writting skills.

Comment: Hello, I was just testing the code from above. I inputted this: michael.jonesáéí@gmail.com and it is raising errors with the code: if (!preg_match("/^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$/", $email)) {

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/8 it works. I suggest you to use a different delimiter. `if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~", $email)) {`

Comment: Hmm then I do not know what I am still doing wrong :( I tried "~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~" and it is still raising errors...

Comment: @Tom: Right. Which is correct. It won't match just *any* letter, it will only match *some* letters. (I mean, don't get me wrong, the sentence is genuinely ambiguous, and the parse that you suggest is certainly the more natural of the two possible parses. I don't blame you for having misunderstood. But both parses are grammatical.)

Comment: @ruakh The problem is, that you can use "any" for "every" or for "some". But he changed that sentence now, so its not an issue anymore.

Comment: @user3448743 it's all with the unicode. See my update.

Comment: if (!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}@+._-]+$~u", $email)) { is my updates code, but still errors! :( I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: You could check this separately. After adding u , it works fine for me.